# what is math behind elliptic curve? (duplicate)

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, private-key, public-key

I have seen many videos regarding the math behind the bitcoin elliptical curve but none of them showing the public key generation they are just defining few steps. i need complete math behind the elliptical curve in which the generation of public key is defined. actually i want to see visual calculation for public key generation, someone give me the link which was defining the math behind elliptical curve

what i understand that is k * n times G is equals to public key but question is remain same if k*n times G (where every point of G we get from point multiplication and point addition ) then at every multiplication of k*G will result a different value then how can we combine them get the public key.